Error in predicting probabilities of conditional logit using statsmodels
I am trying to produce the predicted probabilities of a conditional logistic regression model that is built with a case-control dataset using statsmodels package (0.12.2) in Python. The package provides a clear document on how to build the model and its functions including predict: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models.ConditionalLogit.html. However, the predict function runs into an unclear error when I try to get the predicted probabilities for seen or unseen data. This problem was raised by other people without any suggestion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581390/implementing-a-conditional-logit-in-python-statsmodels. Could anybody please help to find a solution for this error?
Here is a simple example that results in a NotImplementError shown in the screenshot below:
from statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models import ConditionalLogit
import numpy as np
g = np.kron(np.arange(100), np.ones(5)).astype(int)
x = np.random.normal(size=500)
pr = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
y = (np.random.uniform(size=500) < pr).astype(int)
m = ConditionalLogit(endog=y, exog=x, groups=g)
r = m.fit()
r.predict(x)


Despite conditional logit, an unconditional logit model terminates successfully and the same predict function produces the predicted probabilities without any error, as shown below:
import statsmodels.api as sm
m_uncon = sm.Logit(y, x)
r_uncon = m_uncon.fit()
r_uncon.predict(x)



for ConditionalLogit predictions are not available by the design. the model is fit using a conditional likelihood in which the intercepts are not present. And because intercepts are not present you can't predict probabilities.
Same logic can be found in other packages. For example in R:
https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/clogit
Alternative
As an alternative consider using Generalized Linear Mixed Models described here: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-generalized-linear-mixed-models/
from statsmodels.genmod.bayes_mixed_glm import BinomialBayesMixedGLM
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'y': y,
                     'x': x,
                     'g': g})

fml = "y ~ x"
fml_vc = {"a": "0 + C(g)"}
glmm = BinomialBayesMixedGLM.from_formula(fml, fml_vc, data=data)
r = glmm.fit_vb()

print(r.summary())
print(r.random_effects()) # groups means

f = r.predict(data)
print(f)

